# BPT Process Task Box

Tags: outsystems

I see our in our Production web page there is a BPT Task box. But when I try to learn about the process, I cannot see it in the Outsystems Development Service Studio. Does BPT Process is the part of Service Studio or is it done externally. Can anybody please explain me about this. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The BPT task box is a component that is installed in every environment along with all other System Components. For the task box to be shown in your application it needs to be active - which it is by default but you can validate accessing *http://yourserver/EPA_Taskbox* - and you need to have pending tasks.
If you want to learn more about how to implement your first biz process with OutSystems I suggest you look into [this training course](http://www.outsystems.com/academy/16/Modeling+Business+Processes/).

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

because the training course link seems to be dead, you can continue to follow it [here](https://www.outsystems.com/learn/lesson/916/introduction-to-business-processes/)

Cheers